# How to set Map Projection to custom tiled map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I write Apache Cordova application.

I've leaflet map with custom map tiles in my project.
I'm using [this](http://build-failed.blogspot.com/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html) tutorial for adding map to project. That works fine but I want to set Map Projection to my custom map.

Now, my right top corner is `this.marker = L.marker(180,180);`

How to set Map Projection of the project so as to be able to use geographic coordinate system (latitude, longitude) ??

Answer (score 0):

Would [this](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-crs) by chance be what you are looking for?  A fiddle would go a long way toward helping.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    zoom: 13
});
```